# Why bottom line for text field does not follow the constraints rule in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uitextfield, textfield

This is my Utilities file in my project where I set the bottom line for the text field:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Utilities {

    static func styleTextField(_ textfield:UITextField) {
    
        let bottomLine = CALayer()
    
        bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textfield.frame.height - 2, width: textfield.frame.width, height: 2)
    
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 77/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    
        textfield.borderStyle = .none
    
        textfield.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
    
    }
    static func styleFilledButton(_ button:UIButton) {
    
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 77/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        button.tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
    static func styleFilledButtonweb(_ button:UIButton) {
  
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 77/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        button.tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
    static func styleHollowButton(_ button:UIButton) {
    
        button.layer.borderWidth = 2
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 77/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        button.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 77/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
     }
}
```

And this is my View Controller file for using the styleTextField function:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase



class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField! {
        didSet {
            var whitePlaceholderText = NSMutableAttributedString()
            let Name  = "Ad"

            whitePlaceholderText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:Name, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 15)!]) // Font
            whitePlaceholderText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.white, range:NSRange(location:0,length:Name.count))    // Color
            firstNameTextField.attributedPlaceholder = whitePlaceholderText
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField! {
        didSet {
            var whitePlaceholderText = NSMutableAttributedString()
            let Name  = "Soyad"

            whitePlaceholderText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:Name, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 15)!]) // Font
            whitePlaceholderText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.white, range:NSRange(location:0,length:Name.count))    // Color
            lastNameTextField.attributedPlaceholder = whitePlaceholderText
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField! {
        didSet {
            var whitePlaceholderText = NSMutableAttributedString()
            let Name  = "Email"

            whitePlaceholderText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:Name, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 15)!]) // Font
            whitePlaceholderText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.white, range:NSRange(location:0,length:Name.count))    // Color
            emailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = whitePlaceholderText
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField! {
        didSet {
            var whitePlaceholderText = NSMutableAttributedString()
            let Name  = "Şifre"

            whitePlaceholderText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:Name, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 15)!]) // Font
            whitePlaceholderText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.white, range:NSRange(location:0,length:Name.count))    // Color
            passwordTextField.attributedPlaceholder = whitePlaceholderText
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var passworddogrulaTextField: UITextField! {
        didSet {
            var whitePlaceholderText = NSMutableAttributedString()
            let Name  = "Şifreyi Doğrula"

            whitePlaceholderText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:Name, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 15)!]) // Font
            whitePlaceholderText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.white, range:NSRange(location:0,length:Name.count))    // Color
            passworddogrulaTextField.attributedPlaceholder = whitePlaceholderText
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!    

    let Button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    let Button1 = UIButton(type: .custom)


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
        setUpElements()
        show_hide_password(textfield: passwordTextField)
        show_hide_password1(textfield: passworddogrulaTextField)
        self.passwordTextField.delegate = self
        self.passworddogrulaTextField.delegate = self
        self.emailTextField.delegate = self
        self.lastNameTextField.delegate = self
        self.firstNameTextField.delegate = self
    
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    vself.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }

    func show_hide_password(textfield: UITextField) {
        textfield.rightViewMode = .unlessEditing
        Button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "eye.slash.fill"), for: .normal)
        Button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: -24, bottom: 5, right: 15)
        Button.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(textfield.frame.size.width - 25), y: CGFloat(5), width: CGFloat(15), height: CGFloat(25))
        Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnVisibilityClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        textfield.rightView = Button
        textfield.rightViewMode = .always
    }
    func show_hide_password1(textfield: UITextField) {
        textfield.rightViewMode = .unlessEditing
        Button1.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "eye.slash.fill"), for: .normal)
        Button1.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: -24, bottom: 5, right: 15)
        Button1.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(textfield.frame.size.width - 25), y: CGFloat(5), width: CGFloat(15), height: CGFloat(25))
        Button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnVisibilityClicked1), for: .touchUpInside)
        textfield.rightView = Button1
        textfield.rightViewMode = .always
    }

    @IBAction func btnVisibilityClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        (sender as! UIButton).isSelected = !(sender as! UIButton).isSelected
        if (sender as! UIButton).isSelected{
            self.passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = false
            Button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "eye.fill"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            self.passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
            Button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "eye.slash.fill"), for: .normal)
        }
   }
    @IBAction func btnVisibilityClicked1(_ sender: Any) {
        (sender as! UIButton).isSelected = !(sender as! UIButton).isSelected
        if (sender as! UIButton).isSelected{
            self.passworddogrulaTextField.isSecureTextEntry = false
            Button1.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "eye.fill"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            self.passworddogrulaTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
            Button1.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "eye.slash.fill"), for: .normal)
        }
    }

    func setUpElements(){
        errorLabel.alpha = 0
        Utilities.styleTextField(firstNameTextField)
        Utilities.styleTextField(lastNameTextField)
        Utilities.styleTextField(emailTextField)
        Utilities.styleTextField(passwordTextField)
        Utilities.styleTextField(passworddogrulaTextField)
        Utilities.styleFilledButton(signUpButton)
    }
}
```

Here are the screenshots [Connection for the text fields and the screenshot of sign up page storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBKSn.png) for the storyboards and connections between storyboards and view controller:

Even though I declared the constraints, the bottom line does not appear right. What should I do for it to appear correct?

Here is the screenshot of the wrong appearance: [The appearance of the text field in iPhone 12 Pro Max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APJFZ.png)

And here is the screenshot of the correct appearance in the simulator of Xcode for iPhone 11: [The simulator of iPhone 11 and the correct appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rzHT.png)

Thank you for your help! Here is the [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HN7usMROt8&t=1098s) for the draft.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting these before layouts set. If you had your view in a UIView class you could put these in layoutSubviews()
Since you are setting these in viewController, putting setUpElements() into viewDidAppear() will probably solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help! And a additional question. When I add my setUpElements() into viewDidAppear() there is a small delay for setting up the elements. How can avoid that delay?

Comment: i think viewDidLayoutSubviews() is best for you